# HTTP 400 When Calling With Two Route Params

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.7.2

Why is this HTTP request returning a 400?

```
[RoutePrefix("common/api/trusts/{trustID}/periods")]
public class PeriodsController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{trustPeriodID}/getPeriodStartEndDates")]
    public object GetPeriodStartEndDates(short trustID, short trustPeriodID)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here's the call:

```
$http.get("https://localhost:44300/common/api/trusts/1/periods/111811/getPeriodStartEndDates")
.then(function (result) {
     //do something with the result                       
});
```

I'm using Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.3 and Angularjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,the range of  `short` is -32,768 to 32,767, your `trustPeriodID` - 111811 is far beyond the range. You could set its type to `int` instead:

```
public object GetPeriodStartEndDates(short trustID, int trustPeriodID)
```

What's more , make sure you have configured `CORS` based on this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors

For globally enabling CORS, add below code in your `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        //replace the url with your own Angular origin
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4200", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The first part of your answer fixed it. Thanks!